# Testing event chains and module.run() in Angular + Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

**I am trying to test a module that has the following code:**

```
angular.module('angularEnterpriseAuthorization').run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'AppConfig',
  function($rootScope, $state, AppConfig) {

    // On every time the user changes state check to see if the user has permissions to go to the new state
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        // If the state is not one of the public states as defined in the modules config
        if (AppConfig.publicStates.indexOf(toState.name) < 0) {
            event.preventDefault();

            $state.go(toState, toParams, {notify: false}).then(function() {
                      $rootScope.$broadcast('$stateChangeSuccess', toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams);
            }); 
        }
    });
]);
```

**My test looks like this:**

```
beforeEach(module('angularEnterpriseAuthorization', 'coreConfiguration'));


beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$httpBackend_, _AppConfig_) {
    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    AppConfig = _AppConfig_
    spyOn($scope, '$broadcast').andCallThrough();
}));


it('should allow navigation to public states', function() {  
    $scope.$broadcast('$stateChangeStart', [{},{name:AppConfig.publicStates[0]}]);
    expect($scope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalledWith('$stateChangeStart', [{}, {name:     AppConfig.publicStates[0]}]);
    $scope.$broadcast.reset();
    expect($scope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalledWith('$stateChangeSuccess');
});
```

The problem I am having is that the second expect is returning false. I think the issues is that the module is not being initialized with the same $rootScope.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your run block, you subscribe a `$stateChangeStart` on `$rootScope` and also broadcast a `$stateChangeSuccess` event from `$rootScope`.

In your test, you have to do the same, using the `$rootscope`. May be change this line:

```
$scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
```

to just this:

```
$scope = _$rootScope_;
```

And also you have to remove the `$scope.$broadcast.reset()`, that will clear all the remembered calls.

To test the second call of the same method, you could do it like this:

```
it('should allow navigation to public states', function() {  
    $scope.$broadcast('$stateChangeStart', [{},{name:AppConfig.publicStates[0]}]);
    expect($scope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalledWith('$stateChangeStart', [{}, {name:     AppConfig.publicStates[0]}]);
    $scope.$apply();
    expect($scope.$broadcast.calls[1].args[0]).toEqual('$stateChangeSuccess');
});
```

Hope this helps.